# Thick line with square brackets on schematic

Tags: schematics

I was trying to read a schematic and i came across thick lines with square brackets... What do these things mean?

I attach a picture of the aforementioned sight.
[image]

Comment: Instead of drawing all connections between parts, lines are grouped into buses for clarity, typically represented by thicker lines.  Data bus, Address bus, Control bus, School bus, etc.

Comment: Please don't take any style ideas from this...

Comment: Funny how the guy that drew the schematic went to the effort of joining buses but still left almost everything else a mess.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRatOne of those is not like the others... :)

Answer (score 8):

These are buses or groups, as some call them.

You can think of them as bundles of wires or of PCB tracks.

They're used to simplify moving a set of connections around that are usually grouped together anyway because they share characteristics or share sources and destinations. They stop the schematic getting very congested, as it can if the connections were drawn individually.

Connections can join and leave the bus/group and need to be named as they do so. The whole bus/group has a name too, as you noticed. Square brackets denote a numerical range, so [7:0] means 'from 7 down to 0', GPIO[1:2] means 'GPIO1 and GPIO2' etc.

Common ones are data and address buses for digital chips like MPUs, MCUs, memories, and I/O buses for MCUs such as an I/O port.

Comment: The text in the square brackets gives the names of all the signals included in the bus.

Comment: I understand the philosophy, but still i do not get where each individual pin connects to where. Also, how are pins naed? From up to bottom, or bottom to top? Also in the top and right square, there are only two pins and labeled GPA[0...7] How is that possible? Where do these pins connect?

Comment: @user1584421, you're not looking properly. Just as I described, your GPA[0..7] is labelling a bus whereas GPA6 and GPA7 are labelling nets (connections). The former is clearly written horizontally on your schematic and the latter are clearly written vertically. You know that I can't write you a personal tutorial - you have plenty of information to take time and research it for yourself on the internet. There's plenty of detailed text and videos about.